# Instalar IPA usando Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Estou desenvolvendo um APP para **jailbreak**, gostaria de saber como faço para instalar um **.ipa** que eu baixei de meu servidor para poder instalar no aparelho (iPhone e iPad). Meu aplicativo não vem promover a pirataria, somente baixa outros apps do mesmo desenvolvedor, ou seja, meus apps.

Consegui baixar os apps para a pasta `Documents`, mas não sei mais o que fazer com eles. Já tentei extrair e colar na pasta `Applications`, sem resultado.Tentei instalar na pasta trash e funcionou mas não da para desinstalar no modo normal. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue o código:

```
 import UIKit;
    import Foundation;
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var label : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 100));

    var down : Bool = false;
    var ApplicationsFolder : String = "";

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        label.text = "Nothindo to Say!";
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
        label.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
        view.addSubview(label);
    }
    @IBAction func respring(){
        setuid(0); system("sudo reboot");
    }

    @IBAction func download(){
        if(down == false){
            var folderOrError : String = self.searchFolder();

            if(folderOrError.rangeOfString("error") == nil){
                self.down = true;
                self.ApplicationsFolder = folderOrError;

                label.text = "Baixando...";
                setuid(0);
                self.downloadPdf();

            }else{
                self.down = false;
                label.text = "Não foi possivel localizar a pasta de Applicativos!";
            }
        }
        //system("cd Applications \n ls");
    }

    func searchFolder() -> String {
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        //v//ar paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(folderMine, .UserDomainMask, true);
        var documentsDirectory : String;
        documentsDirectory = "/var/stash/";//paths[0] as String
        var fileManager: NSFileManager = NSFileManager()

        var fileList: NSArray = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentsDirectory, error: nil)!

        for s in fileList {

            var temp : String = s as String;
            var contenad : String = documentsDirectory+temp+"/";
            //println(contenad);
            if( contenad.rangeOfString(".lnk") == nil){
                var applicationList : NSArray = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(contenad, error: nil)!

                for n in applicationList {
                    var temp1 : String = n as String;
                    if(temp1.rangeOfString("Applications") != nil ){
                        return contenad+"Applications/";
                    }
                }
            }

        }


        return "error";
    }

    func fileExist(documentsDirectory : String, fileName : String) -> Bool {
        var fileManager: NSFileManager = NSFileManager()

        var fileList: NSArray = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentsDirectory, error: nil)!

        for s in fileList {

            var temp : String = s as String;

            if( temp.rangeOfString(fileName) == nil){
                return true;
            }

        }


        return false;
    }

    func saveFile(fileContent : String, file : String){
        let dirs : [String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]

        println(dirs![0]);

        if ((dirs) != nil) {
            let dir = dirs![0]; //documents directory
            let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);
            let text = fileContent;

            //writing
            text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil);

            //reading
            let text2 = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        }
    }

    /*func downloadPdf()
    {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/repo/download.php")
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
            var returnMsg = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;
            self.saveFile(returnMsg, file: "fileb.ipa");
        }

        task.resume()




    }*/



    func downloadPdf()
    {
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://10.0.1.8/repo/PixlrExpressPlus.zip")!)
        let session = AFHTTPSessionManager()

        var progress: NSProgress?

        var downloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request, progress: &progress, destination: {(data, responce) in self.pathUrl;
            },
            completionHandler:
            {
                response, localfile, error in
                /*println("response do download \(localfile)")

                self.label.text = "Downloaded";
                let aString: String = localfile.absoluteString!;
                let newString = aString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("file://", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil);

                let folderFile = newString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".zip", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil);

                //system("ditto");
                //system("sudo chmod 777 \(newString)");
                //system("mkdir /var/mobile/Application/UHeuEHuHEuehuHEuHEuHEuEH");
                system("mv \(newString) /var/mobile/Application//filea.ipa")
                //system("cd Application \n ls");

                let dirs : [String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String];
                let dir = dirs![0];
                SSZipArchive.unzipFileAtPath(newString, toDestination: dir);
                self.label.text = "Instalando..";
                setuid(0);
                system("chmod -R 777 \(folderFile)");
                //system("sudo mv -f \(newString) /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/myNewApp.ipa");
                system("dpkg -b \(folderFile)");
                self.label.text = "deu erro";
                //UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: aString)!)*/
                self.label.text = "Instalando...";
                let aString: String = localfile.absoluteString!;
                let newString = aString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("file://", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil);



                let folderFile = newString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".zip", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil);

                SSZipArchive.unzipFileAtPath(newString, toDestination: folderFile);

                let appFile = folderFile+"/PixlrExpressPlus.app";
                setuid(0);
                //println("(sudo mv -f \(appFile) \(self.ApplicationsFolder)PixlrExpressPlus.app)");
                system("sudo mv -f \(appFile) \(self.ApplicationsFolder)PixlrExpressPlus.app");
                if( self.fileExist(self.ApplicationsFolder, fileName: self.ApplicationsFolder+"PixlrExpressPlus.app")){
                    setuid(0); system("sudo chmod -R 777 \(self.ApplicationsFolder)PixlrExpressPlus.app");
                    self.label.text = "Instalado com Sucesso! Por Favor, Respringue!";
                    //system("killall SpringBoard");
                }else{
                    self.label.text = "Deu problema com o Root!";
                }

        })



        downloadTask.resume();

    }

    var pathUrl: NSURL{

        let dirs : [String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String];
        let dir = dirs![0];

        let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("PixlrExpressPlus.zip");
        //let diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(7));
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path);//self.ApplicationsFolder+"temporari\(diceRoll).zip");

        return url!;
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: Faz o upload através desse site: http://www.diawi.com/ Após o upload clica em **Send**, depois disso acessa o link que ele vai gerar através do navegador do seu iPhone ou iPad e segue os passos.

Answer (score 0):

Para distribuir qualquer app fora da AppStore é necessário ter uma conta Enterprise [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/). Sem uma conta Enterprise só é possível distribuir um app para dispositivos cadastrados na sua conta de desenvolvedor.

Depois de assinar seu app com um certificado enterprise você deve seguir os passos que se encontra nesse guia [Install in-house apps wirelessly](http://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/apda0e3426d7)

Seguindo esses passos você conseguirá instalar tanto de uma página web utilizando o safari ou dentro de um app que você estiver desenvolvendo para esse fim.